# Data is not visible in the list

Tags: list, data-binding, windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone 8 application when user clicks on the button, i'm calling the web service and get the result in the variable of type List.
After that I'm trying to bind the result to list in xaml page. But the data is not visible.

```
//Data Context object
class Company
    {      
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public string CityId { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public string CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string Phone1 { get; set; }

    public string Mobile1 { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Fax { get; set; }

    public string Website { get; set; }

    public string Profile { get; set; }

    public string Latitude { get; set; }

    public string Longitude { get; set; }

    public string Sponsored { get; set; }
}
```

In my XAML page i'm binding the above result to List.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="3" Background="White" Margin="0,-3,0,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="companiesList"  
                 SelectionChanged="companiesList_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="listItem">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock x:Name="nameTextBlock" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding CompanyName}" Foreground="#FF501F6E" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="28" MaxHeight="40" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Margin="5,0,0,5"/>

                        <TextBlock x:Name="addressTextBlock"  Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Address}" Foreground="#FF1F1F1F" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20" MaxHeight="30" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Margin="5,0,0,5"/>

                        <StackPanel x:Name="addressPanel" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,5">
                            <Image x:Name="phone" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="0,0,5,0" Height="25" Source="Images/list_phone.png"  />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="phoneTextBlock" Text="{Binding Phone1}" Foreground="#FF501F6E" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20" MaxHeight="30" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <Image  x:Name="line" Grid.Row="3" Width="460" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/separator.png"  />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

After that in code behind file, i'm binding like below.

```
  private void CompaniesPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (isPageAlreadyLoaded == false)
        {                
            List<Company> companies = (List<Company>)DataContext;
            companiesList.ItemsSource = companies;
            isPageAlreadyLoaded = true;
        }
    }
```

While debugging I've checked the variable **List companies** variable in the code behind file before setting to list and i'm **getting the data correctly**.
But the data is not binding to the list. I don't know why data was not binding.

Now to test i've **replaced the binding with static text**. And I run the application then also **data is not visible in the page**. **But on list item changed i'm getting the data.** This means that my xaml page is unable to display data. So could you please tell me what was the wrong in my xaml page design which is at below.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="STCDirectory.CompaniesPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" Loaded="CompaniesPage_Loaded"
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=WindowsPhoneWatermarkTextBoxControl">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="/STCDirectory;component/Images/search_list_bg.png" />
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,10" >
        <TextBlock x:Name="header" Text="STC Directory" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,20,0,5"  Foreground="#FF501F6E" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="35" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="buttonsBar" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <Button Content="Button" Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,1,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,1,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="searchBar" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <my:WatermarkTextBox Name="textBlock1" Width="400" Margin="-5,0,-10,0" WatermarkText="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.SearchHint, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" TextAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontSize="25">
            <my:WatermarkTextBox.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/STCDirectory;component/Images/search_box.png" />
            </my:WatermarkTextBox.Background>
        </my:WatermarkTextBox>
        <Button x:Name="serchButton" Style ="{StaticResource ButtonStyleIB}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="70"  Click="serach_button_clicked">
            <Image Source="/STCDirectory;component/Images/search.png" Stretch="Fill" />
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="3" Background="White" Margin="0,-3,0,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="companiesList"  
                 SelectionChanged="companiesList_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="listItem">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock x:Name="nameTextBlock" Grid.Row="0" Text="Kentuc Fried Chicken(KFC)" Foreground="#FF501F6E" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="28" MaxHeight="40" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Margin="5,0,0,5"/>

                        <TextBlock x:Name="addressTextBlock"  Grid.Row="1" Text="Al riyadh" Foreground="#FF1F1F1F" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20" MaxHeight="30" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Margin="5,0,0,5"/>

                        <StackPanel x:Name="addressPanel" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,5">
                            <Image x:Name="phone" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="0,0,5,0" Height="25" Source="Images/list_phone.png"  />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="phoneTextBlock" Text="966123456" Foreground="#FF501F6E" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20" MaxHeight="30" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <Image  x:Name="line" Grid.Row="3" Width="460" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/separator.png"  />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I'm looking forward for your response
Thanks,
Basina

Comment: I don't remember if it's required on Windows Phone, but just in case I'd suggest setting the Company class as public: `public class Company`

Comment: hi Kookiz, I've changed the class as public and then also page is not displaying data.

Answer (score 0):

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        List<Company> companies = new List<Company>();
        Company comp = new Company();
        comp.CompanyName = "hellocpmp1";
        companies.Add(comp);
        companies.Add(comp);
        companies.Add(comp);
        companies.Add(comp);
        companies.Add(comp);

        companies.Add(comp);
        companies.Add(comp);

        companies.Add(comp);

        companies.Add(comp);
        companies.Add(comp);
        companies.Add(comp);



        companiesList.ItemsSource = companies;
    }
```

i have tried it like above and it is working fine so in your case thr may be problem with no data coming from web service.

Comment: In my question at last line I've mentioned, i'm getting the data from web service and i'm passing the data to the page which has list  item successfully. And also i'm checking that data is coming or not before assigning it to list.

Comment: but i have tried your code it coming so what you can do is just try according to what i have done and check whether according to me it is right or wrong ..i also removed your textbox styles.

Comment: Hi Tanuj, I've edited my question. Please find my whole ui page code in the question. I've replaced the binding options with static text and i run the application. Then also the static text is not visible in the page. So this means that some thing went wrong with my xaml page. I didn't find the mistake where exactly. Could you please test this page with static text as it is. I'm looking forward for your response. Thanks Basina

Answer (score 0):

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="PhoneApp1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls;assembly=Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d"



shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"  Background="Transparent" >
    <ListBox x:Name="companiesList"  ItemsSource="{Binding companies}"
             SelectionChanged="companiesList_SelectionChanged_2">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <Grid x:Name="listItem">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock x:Name="nameTextBlock" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding CompanyName}" Foreground="#FF501F6E" />

                    <TextBlock x:Name="addressTextBlock"  Grid.Row="1" Text="Al riyadh" Foreground="#FF1F1F1F" />

                    <StackPanel x:Name="addressPanel" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,5">
                        <Image x:Name="phone" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="0,0,5,0" Height="25" Source="Images/list_phone.png"  />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="phoneTextBlock" Text="966123456" Foreground="#FF501F6E" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <Image  x:Name="line" Grid.Row="3" Width="460" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/separator.png"  />
                </Grid>



            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

i have found your problem thr is something wrong with your style part of your textblocks so i have removed it . i have put some working code with binding as well as hardcoded text . tell me if your problem got solved.

Comment: Hi Friends,

Thanks for all your responses. I've solved the issue by putting the text blocks inside stackpanel and placing the width property to stack panel like below.

<StackPanel x:Name="namePanel" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,5" Height="50">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="nameTextBlock" Text="{Binding CompanyName}" Foreground="#FF501F6E" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="28" MaxHeight="40" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="460" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                   </StackPanel>

Comment: what i have told you thr is an issue with your layout part and nothing wrong with the binding part.